# Визуализация данных Qt

Tags: график, qt, c++, визуализация

Какие существуют свободные решения для визуализации данных в Qt. Интересуют в первую очередь обычные Качественные графики x-y. Иногда отображение изолиний.
UPD По возможности не qwt. Хотя если есть у кого положительный опыт использования - подскажите что почитать, с чего начать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Взгляните на [HippoDraw](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/grp/ek/hippodraw/). Может использоваться как приложение и как библиотека. Имеет интерфейсы для C++ и Python. Графика не особо, но если это не критично, то вполне может устроить.

Comment: То что нужно! Спасибо! =)

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать самому сваять с помощью этого элемента [QGraphicsView](http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.7.x/graphicsview.html)

Comment: Да можно и сваять. Просто задача несколько другая и на ваяние граиков не особо много времени. Что-нибудь бы более остро заточенное под вывод графиков. Ну а вообще подумаю. Спасибо.